# Picasso Does not display Image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I try to load image with android studio kotlin app using Picasso. i am not able to load image.
i have written my code below. could any one tell me what mistakes i made in my code.

in Mainactivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        val myApi = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.59.85")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MyData::class.java)
        myApi.getData().enqueue(object :Callback<List<MydatsItem>>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<MydatsItem>>,
                response: Response<List<MydatsItem>>
            ) {
                val recycle = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclr)
                recycle.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)

                response.body()?.let {

                val adapter = MyAdapter(this@MainActivity,it)
                    recycle.adapter= adapter
                }


                Log.d("goo",response.body().toString())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MydatsItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("goo",t.message.toString())

            }

        })
    }


}
interface MyData{
    @GET("/kicker-music/wordpress/wp-json/kicker-api/get-cat")
    fun getData(): Call<List<MydatsItem>>
}
```

in my adapter class file

```
class MyAdapter(val context:Context, val Items:List<MydatsItem>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewholder>() {
    class MyViewholder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val catName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt)
        val image = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewholder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_categary,parent,false)
        return MyViewholder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewholder, position: Int) {
        holder.catName.text = Items[position].cat_name
        Picasso.get().load(Items[position].image).into(holder.image);

    }
}
```

here is my data class

```
data class MydatsItem( 
    val cat_name: String,
    val image: String
)
```

i Want to load image in my recycler view using Picasso.

Comment: Does this have to do anything with recycle view? Why not post simple code where you try to load one image in one ImageView. But can you? Dit you try?

Comment: i try to load image from api  server into recyclerview using Picasso.but it down't display image into recyclerview.

Comment: Images are displayed in ImageView's. So post code using one ImageView only. I think using recycle view is irrelevant. And you did not answer my questions in my first comment. Any reason?

Comment: Consider to initialize ```RecyclerView``` and ```Adapter``` outside of API request callback. Also, consider to use Glide - it has (or at least had) a better performance compare to others alternative solutions. Regarding ```Picasso```, it should support extensive logging and ```onComlpete()``` and ```onError()``` callbacks, please try to add them and see are they called or not.

Comment: I think onResponse() is never triggered. Please elaborate.

Comment: This is a pretty strange construct as you are not letting Picasso download the image itself but Retrofit. Why did you decide for this? Or what exactly is the Retrofit call delivering?